# negative binomial model calculated with mle2 does not change after an offset is added to the function

Tags: r, bioinformatics, offset, glm

The model that is created with an offset added as correction to the mle2 function is not different from the model that is created with mle2 without an offset, am I adding the offset in a correct way?

Also when the glm.nb and mle2 model give different values when the offset is added, which one is the most reliable?

I'm trying to find out which model fits best on microbiome count data. At this point I want to know if a CSS transformation will result in a better fit. The first step of dealing with the data is to remove the outliers based on the Cook's distance. Then we want to fit a negative binomial model to the data and see whether doing a transformation wil result in a better fitting model. Mle2 and glm.nb can both be used for creating the negative binomial model.

Based on https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_possible_to_use_quasi-poisson_or_negative_binominal_regression_with_continuous_dependent_variable I decided to add the correction of the CSS normalization as an offset instead of adding the continuous normalized count data in the glm.nb model. This does result in different p-values for the glm.nb model, but not for the mle2 model. 
The mle2 p-values remain the same as when no offset is added to the function. How do I add the offset correctly and which of the two models would you advise me to use for this problem?

```r
offset_value <- c(13.785, 59.853, 15.016,  4.359,  8.161, 47.673,  4.277,  7.591,  4.957,  9.360,  9.985, 11.684,  0.803, 16.411,  6.492,  0.785, 10.782,  6.153,  6.662,  6.744,
4.201,  5.171,  7.553,  1.577,  8.512,  5.661,  3.575,  2.953,  6.407,  8.092,  6.536, 17.086,  2.259, 25.144, 17.323,  5.923,  9.660,  2.871,  3.246,  4.276,
2.114,  2.008,  9.466,  7.283, 31.060,  6.331,  6.363,  4.347, 10.638, 12.250,  5.470, 59.175, 11.102, 10.594, 13.949,  1.631,  6.941,  7.872,  3.357, 10.474,
3.722,  2.448,  9.783, 40.251, 18.991,  3.925,  1.271,  5.352,  3.764,  6.321,  6.846, 27.236, 35.357,  6.651,  4.609,  7.014,  3.401, 48.997,  3.765,  2.841,
5.065, 3.049,  4.670,  7.570, 10.249,  4.834,  1.099,  2.154,  2.745, 22.123,  2.343,  5.216,  2.883,  3.152,  1.617,  8.851,  4.825,  4.770,  1.864,  3.551,
38.087,  1.643,  2.783)

offset_value <- c(13.785, 59.853, 15.016,  4.359,  8.161, 47.673,  4.277,  7.591,  4.957,  9.360,  9.985, 11.684,  0.803, 16.411,  6.492,  0.785, 10.782,  6.153,  6.662,  6.744,
                  4.201,  5.171,  7.553,  1.577,  8.512,  5.661,  3.575,  2.953,  6.407,  8.092,  6.536, 17.086,  2.259, 25.144, 17.323,  5.923,  9.660,  2.871,  3.246,  4.276,
                  2.114,  2.008,  9.466,  7.283, 31.060,  6.331,  6.363,  4.347, 10.638, 12.250,  5.470, 59.175, 11.102, 10.594, 13.949,  1.631,  6.941,  7.872,  3.357, 10.474,
                  3.722,  2.448,  9.783, 40.251, 18.991,  3.925,  1.271,  5.352,  3.764,  6.321,  6.846, 27.236, 35.357,  6.651,  4.609,  7.014,  3.401, 48.997,  3.765,  2.841,
                  5.065, 3.049,  4.670,  7.570, 10.249,  4.834,  1.099,  2.154,  2.745, 22.123,  2.343,  5.216,  2.883,  3.152,  1.617,  8.851,  4.825,  4.770,  1.864,  3.551,
                  38.087,  1.643,  2.783)

count_data <- c(  51,  68,  15,  15,   8,  13,  36, 109,   0,   0,   7,  15,   0,  10,  21,   0,   0,  12,  10,  12,   0,   0, 101,   0,   0,   0,   7,   0,   0,  18,  10, 127,   0,  13,  17,
                  8,  73,   9,   7,   0,   0,   0,  51,  45,  17,   0,  43,  17,  21, 133,  10, 181,  16,  42,  20,  11,   0,   0,  12,   0,   0,   0, 138,   0,  37,  28,  13,   8,   0,  13,
                  38,   7, 462,   7,   0,   0,   0,   8,  10,   0,   0,   6,   7,   9,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   6,   6,   0,   0,   0,   0,  48,   8,   0,   0,   8,  10,   6,   0)

subtypes <- c("c", "c", "c", "a", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "a", "c", "a","c", "c", "b","c", "c", "c", "c", "b","b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "b",
              "a","b","a","b","a","c", "b","a","a","b","a","c","b","a","c", "a","a","c", "a","a","a","c", "a","c", "b","a","b","c","b","c", "b","a"
              ,"a","b","b","c","a","a","c","a","a","a","c", "a","a","c", "a","c", "a","b","c", "c","a","a","a","c", "c", "c", "a","c", "b","b","b","b",
              "a","a","a","a","c", "a","a","c", "c", "a","a")


# make a dataframe for mle2
df <- data.frame(count_data, subtypes, offset_value)

#data for glm.nb
data = NULL
subtypes = data.frame(subtypes)
data$subtypes = subtypes

#show the coefficients of the model with offset and without offset

summary(mle2(read_counts~dnbinom(mu=exp(logmu),size=exp(logk)),parameters=list(logmu~subtypes+offset(log(offset_value))), start=list(logmu=0,logk=0), data=df))@coef

summary(mle2(read_counts~dnbinom(mu=exp(logmu),size=exp(logk)),parameters=list(logmu~subtypes), start=list(logmu=0,logk=0), data=df))@coef

# same for glm.nb glm.nb without offset gives exactly the same p_values as mle2
summary(glm.nb(count_data~ subtype, data=data))$coef

summary(glm.nb(count_data~ subtype+offset(log(offset_value))u, data=data))
```

These are the results I obtain. I expected the first results of mle2 with offset to be different from the one without offset.

```r
>
summary(mle2(count_data~dnbinom(mu=exp(logmu),size=exp(logk)),parameters=list(logmu~subtypes+offset(log(offset_value))), start=list(logmu=0,logk=0), data=df))@coef
                     Estimate Std. Error     z value        Pr(z)
logmu.(Intercept)  3.15472530  0.3104631 10.16135368 2.949524e-24
logmu.subtypesb   -0.02963553  0.5587259 -0.05304127 9.576990e-01
logmu.subtypesc   -0.13918805  0.4754000 -0.29278088 7.696896e-01
logk              -1.50131701  0.1527906 -9.82597947 8.702390e-23
> summary(mle2(count_data~dnbinom(mu=exp(logmu),size=exp(logk)),parameters=list(logmu~subtypes), start=list(logmu=0,logk=0), data=df))@coef
                     Estimate Std. Error     z value        Pr(z)
logmu.(Intercept)  3.15472530  0.3104631 10.16135368 2.949524e-24
logmu.subtypesb   -0.02963553  0.5587259 -0.05304127 9.576990e-01
logmu.subtypesc   -0.13918805  0.4754000 -0.29278088 7.696896e-01
logk              -1.50131701  0.1527906 -9.82597947 8.702390e-23

> # glm.nb without offset gives exactly the same p_values as mle2 and not the same p_value as the glm.nb with offset as expected. 

> summary(glm.nb(count_data~ subtypes, data=data))$coef
               Estimate Std. Error     z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  3.15473439  0.3104645 10.16133591 2.950062e-24
subtypesb   -0.02964609  0.5587266 -0.05306011 9.576840e-01
subtypesc   -0.13919949  0.4754007 -0.29280454 7.696716e-01

> summary(glm.nb(count_data~subtypes+offset(log(offset_value)), data=data))$coef
              Estimate Std. Error    z value    Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.8189174  0.2685144  3.0498080 0.002289877
subtypesb    0.0749696  0.4827433  0.1552991 0.876585510
subtypesc   -0.1578136  0.4104105 -0.3845261 0.700588563
```

Comment: I'll take a look, but: can you try a simple example where you know the correct answer and see what happens?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @Ben Bolker! I do not have an example where I know the correct answer of adding the offset to the mle2 function. I expect it to be close to the one of the glm.nb with the added offset, because they do the same thing.